# Delphi TcxGrid correct split rows in columns

Tags: delphi

I have three columns in my TcxGrid and i need to split every time i found the "|" to the next column.
So i need to have this:
Nome    Cognome    Telefono
a       a          33

I've been thinking about work on every column and find if the next character is "|" but i don't know if i can do it with the Find method.

[enter My code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUE7u.png)

[image: output]

Comment: @MartynA He just wants to split a string that contains `|` separators (e.g. `a|b|3`).

Comment: Exactly, i need to split a string to the next column when it meets this "|"

Comment: @Marcol1no Post your code as text, **not** as screenshot. Use the "Code Sample" button (`{}`).

Comment: @UliGerhardt I've tryed with the brackets but it won't display my code correctly...

Comment: Then enter your code as pure test. Someone **will** format it. :-)

Comment: Images of code are not acceptable here. Code is text, and can be copied and pasted directly into your post. Please [edit] to remove the code image and replace it with your code in text form. For more information, see [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use the good old `TStringList`:

```
var
  SL: TStringList;
  iFile, I : Integer;
begin
  SL := TStringList.Create;
  try
    SL.Delimiter := '|';
    SL.StrictDelimiter := true;
    for iFile := 0 to aFile.Count - 1 do
    begin
      SL.DelimitedText := aFile[iFile];
      for I := 0 to SL.Count - 1 do
        cxGrid1TableView1.DataController.Values[iFile, I] := SL[I];
    end;    
  finally
    SL.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Now it's correctly splitted, but my regex (created with RegexBuddy) doesn't work... How can i match my regex to the all lines in SL[I] ? I've tryed with
'Regex.Subject := SL[I];
  if (Regex.Match) then
  begin
    Regex.SubExpressions[Regex.NamedSubExpression('Name')]; 
    showmessage(Regex.SubExpressions[Regex.NamedSubExpression('Name')]);
  end;'

Comment: Please create a new question for this, with the code you’ve tried so far!

Comment: it doens't let me create a new post because it's not formatted very well...
I've put only this <pre><code>MY CODE...</pre></code>
How can i format it correctly ?

Comment: If you can help me this is the new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67124685/delphi-apply-regex-to-tcxgrid-rows

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that (Just out of my head, not tested):

```
var
    A : TStringDynArray;
    J, K : Integer;
    // Some of your code omitted
begin
    // Some of your code omitted
    for J := 0 to aFile.Count - 1 do begin
        A := SplitString(aFile[J], '|'); 
        for K := 0 to Length(A) - 1 do
            cxGrid1TableView1.DataController.Values[J, K] := A[K];
    end;    
    // Some of your code omitted
end;
```

If your Delphi version do not support SplitString, you can do like this:

```
var
    I, J, K, L : Integer;
    S, T    : String;
    // Some of your code omitted
begin
    // Some of your code omitted
    for J := 0 to aFile.Count - 1 do begin
        S := aFile[J]; 
        L := 0;
        I := 1;
        while I <= Length(S) do begin
             K := I;
             while (K <= Length(S)) and (S[K] <> '|') do
                 Inc(K);
             if K > Length(S) then
                 T := Copy(S, I, K - I + 1)
             else 
                 T := Copy(S, I, K - I);
            cxGrid1TableView1.DataController.Values[J, L] := T;
            Inc(L);
            I := K + 1;
        end;
    end;    
    // Some of your code omitted
end;
```

Comment: @fpiette Thanks for you advice, but my delphi version i think doesn't accept the TStringDynArray :(

Comment: @Marco1no TStringDynArray exists for a really very long time. You must find in which unit it is for your version (Types or SysUtils or...). Use Delphi "Find in files" to search Delphi source directory. By the way, which Delphi version are you using?

Comment: @fpiette Delphi2007... I've searched with CTRL+MAIUSC+F but i can't find it

Comment: @Marcol1no I edited my answer to use only very old Delphi features: No TStringDynArray and no SplitString. I have not D2007 to check, but I'm almost sure that it will compile. And by the way, why don't you upgrade to the latest Delphi version? It has tremendous enhancements compared to D2007.

Comment: Fwiw the earliest reference I can find in Marco's Delphi books is the one on Delphi XE.